# The connection closed when code running. which use pyppeteer to crawl a web

Tags: python, pyppeteer

I make a test that crawler taobao.com by use pyppeteer. the taobao.com have identify code, which is the slider button, so I have add some method in code. but the error happend when the code running. the error info like that:

> 2018-11-30 18:15:32 [websockets.protocol] DEBUG: client ! failing
>   WebSocket connection in the OPEN state: 1006 [no reason]   2018-11-30
>   18:15:32 [websockets.protocol] DEBUG: client - event =
>   connection_lost(None)   2018-11-30 18:15:32 [websockets.protocol]
>   DEBUG: client - state = CLOSED   2018-11-30 18:15:32
>   [websockets.protocol] DEBUG: client x code = 1006, reason = [no
>   reason]   2018-11-30 18:15:32 [websockets.protocol] DEBUG: client -
>   aborted pending ping: 7ac33fd3   [I:pyppeteer.connection] connection
>   closed   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most
>   likely the page has been closed.
>   ***********************************:slide login False   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has
>   been closed. ***********************************:slide login False
>   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely
>   the page has been closed. ***********************************:slide
>   login False   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed.
>   Most likely the page has been closed.
>   ***********************************:slide login False   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has
>   been closed. ***********************************:slide login False
>   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely
>   the page has been closed. ***********************************:slide
>   login False   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed.
>   Most likely the page has been closed.
>   ***********************************:slide login False   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has
>   been closed. ***********************************:slide login False
>   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely
>   the page has been closed. ***********************************:slide
>   login False   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed.
>   Most likely the page has been closed.
>   ***********************************:slide login False   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has
>   been closed. ***********************************:slide login False
>   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely
>   the page has been closed. ***********************************:slide
>   login False   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed.
>   Most likely the page has been closed.
>   ***********************************:slide login False   Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has
>   been closed. ***********************************:slide login False

.... dead loop like above infomation.

the error happend after the slider button roll several times,(the slider button need roll more times), but it should be continue until the action success. because I set retry in the code. I wondering why the connection closed.

The core code like that

```
**#middlewares.py**

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from logging import getLogger
import asyncio
import time, os
from pyppeteer.launcher import launch
from seleniumtest.moveslider import mouse_slide, input_time_random
from seleniumtest.jsflagsetter import js1, js3, js4, js5

class SeleniumMiddleware():
    def __init__(self,username=None, password=None, timeout=None):
        self.logger = getLogger(__name__);
        self.username=username;
        self.password=password;
        self.timeout = timeout;
        print("Init downloaderMiddleware use pypputeer.") 
        os.environ['PYPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION'] ='588429' 
        # pyppeteer.DEBUG = False 
        print(os.environ.get('PYPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION'))

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop();
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.getbrowser());
        loop.run_until_complete(task);

    async def getbrowser(self): 
        self.browser = await launch({
            'headless': False, 
            'userDataDir':'tmp',
            'args': ['--no-sandbox'], 
            'executablePath': "C:\\Users\\Edwin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", 
            'dumpio':True
            }
        )
        self.page = await self.browser.newPage();

    async def usePypuppeteer(self, current_page, url):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3);
        await self.page.setUserAgent(
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36') 
        await self.page.setViewport({'width': 1366, 'height': 768 });        
        response = await self.page.goto(url, options={'timeout': self.timeout * 1000}); 
        if response.status != 200:
            return None;

        # evaluate with script
        await self.page.evaluate(js1) 
        await self.page.evaluate(js3)
        await self.page.evaluate(js4)
        await self.page.evaluate(js5)

        if current_page == 1:
            try:
                login_text = await self.page.Jeval('.qrcode-login .login-title', 'node => node.textContent');
            except Exception as e:
                login_text = None;

            if login_text:
                if login_text == '手机扫码，安全登录':
                    switch_btn = await self.page.querySelector('.login-switch #J_Quick2Static');
                    await self.page.evaluate('(element) => element.click()', switch_btn);
                else:
                    pass;

                user_edit = await self.page.querySelector('.login-text.J_UserName');
                await self.page.evaluate('(element) => element.value = ""', user_edit);
                await user_edit.type(self.username, {'delay': input_time_random()}); 
                await self.page.type('#J_StandardPwd #TPL_password_1', self.password, {'delay': input_time_random()})
                time.sleep(1)

            slider = await self.page.Jeval('#nocaptcha', 'node => node.style') 
            if slider:
                flag = await mouse_slide(page=self.page)

                if flag:
                    try:
                        print('******************** get logging button');
                        login_btn = await self.page.querySelector('#J_SubmitStatic'); 
                        await self.page.evaluate('(element) => element.click()', login_btn);
                        await self.page.waitForSelector('#mainsrp-itemlist .m-itemlist');
                        await self.get_cookie(self.page);
                        content = await self.page.content();
                        return content;
                    except Exception as e:
                        return None;
                else:
                    return None;
            else:
                try:
                    await self.page.keyboard.press('Enter')   #press enter
                    await self.page.waitFor(20)
                    await self.page.waitForSelector('#mainsrp-itemlist .m-itemlist');
                    content = await self.page.content();
                    return content;
                except Exception as e:
                    return None;
        else:
            try:
                input = await self.page.querySelector('#mainsrp-pager div.form > input');
                submit = await self.page.querySelector('#mainsrp-pager div.form > span.btn.J_Submit');
                await self.page.evaluate('(element) => element.value = ""', input);
                await input.type(current_page);
                await submit.click();
                await self.page.waitForSelector('#mainsrp-itemlist .m-itemlist');
                current_page_text = await self.page.Jeval('#mainsrp-pager li.item.active > span', 'node => node.textContent');
                items = await self.page.Jeval('.m-itemlist .items .item');
                if current_page_text == str(current_page) and items:
                    content = await self.page.content();
                    return content;
                else:
                    return None;
            except Exception as e:
                return None;


    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.logger.debug('Browser is Starting');
        current_page= request.meta.get('page', 1);
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop();
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.usePypuppeteer(current_page, request.url));
        loop.run_until_complete(task);
        return HtmlResponse(url=request.url, body=task.result(), encoding="utf-8",request=request, status=200);

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls(username=crawler.settings.get('USERNAME'), 
            password=crawler.settings.get('PASSWORD'), 
            timeout=crawler.settings.get('TIMEOUT')
        ); 
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened) 
        return s

    async def get_cookie(page):
        res = await page.content()
        cookies_list = await page.cookies()
        cookies = ''
        for cookie in cookies_list:
            str_cookie = '{0}={1};'
            str_cookie = str_cookie.format(cookie.get('name'), cookie.get('value'))
            cookies += str_cookie
        return cookies

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider): 
        return response;

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider): 
        pass

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name);


**#moveslider.py**
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from retrying import retry
import time, asyncio, random

def retry_if_result_none(result):
    return result is None

def tries(func):
    def func_wrapper(f):
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            while True:
                try:
                    if func(await f(*args, **kwargs)):
                        continue
                    else:
                        break
                except Exception as exc:
                    pass
            return True
        return wrapper
    return func_wrapper

@tries(retry_if_result_none)
async def mouse_slide(page=None):
    try:
        await page.hover('#nc_1_n1z')    #move to slider button
        await page.mouse.down()             # press tee mouse
        await page.mouse.move(1700, 0, {'delay': random.randint(1000, 2000)})   # move mouse to speial location
        await page.mouse.up()                 # release mouse
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, '***********************************:slide login False')
        slider_move_text = await page.Jeval('.errloading .nc-lang-cnt', 'node => node.textContent');  #get 
        print('**********************,slider_move_text=', slider_move_text);
        if "哎呀，出错了，点击" in slider_move_text:
            refresh_btn = await page.querySelector('.errloading .nc-lang-cnt a');
            await page.evaluate('(element) => element.click()', refresh_btn);
            await asyncio.sleep(3);
        return None
    else:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        slider_again = await page.Jeval('.nc-lang-cnt', 'node => node.textContent')
        if slider_again != '验证通过':
            return None
        else:
            await page.screenshot({'path': './headless-slide-result.png'})
            return 1

def input_time_random():
    return random.randint(100, 151)

**#taobao.py**
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request, Spider
from urllib.parse import quote
from seleniumtest.items import ProductItem
import json

class TaobaoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'taobao'
    allowed_domains = ['www.taobao.com']
    base_url = 'https://s.taobao.com/search?q='

    def start_requests(self):
        for keyword in self.settings.get('KEYWORDS'):
            for page in range(1, self.settings.get('MAX_PAGE')+1):
                url = self.base_url + quote(keyword);
                yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={'page':page}, dont_filter=True);

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('//div[@id="mainsrp-itemlist"]//div[@class="items"][1]//div[contains(@class,"item")]');
        for product in products:
            item = ProductItem();
            item['price'] = ''.join(product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"price")]//text()').extract()).strip();
            item['title'] = ''.join(product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"title")]//text()').extract()).strip();
            item['shop'] = ''.join(product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"shop")]//text()').extract()).strip();
            item['image'] = ''.join(product.xpath('.//div[@class="pic"]//img[contains(@class,"img")]/@data-src').extract()).strip();
            item['deal'] = product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"deal-cnt")]//textxt()').extract_first();
            item['location'] = product.xpath('.//div[@class="location"]//text()').extract_first();
            print(item['price'], item['title'], item['shop'], item['image'], item['deal'], item['location']);
            yield item;
```

Comment: I fixed the problem through modify  __init__ method in pyppeteer/connection.py. only add two parameters ping_interval=None and ping_timeout=None in websockets.client.connect().

Answer (score 1):

For now, we have a workaround hack:

```
def patch_pyppeteer():
    import pyppeteer.connection
    original_method = pyppeteer.connection.websockets.client.connect

    def new_method(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['ping_interval'] = None
        kwargs['ping_timeout'] = None
        return original_method(*args, **kwargs)

    pyppeteer.connection.websockets.client.connect = new_method

patch_pyppeteer()
```

Hopefully this pull request [#160](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/pull/160) will be merged soon.