# Pyppeteer crushes after 20 seconds with pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, chromium, pyppeteer

During usage of [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) for controlling the Chromium I have been receiving an error approximately after 20 seconds of work:

```
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
```

As described [here](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/175) the issue is probably caused by implementation of python `websockets>=7` package and by its usage within pyppeteer.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 solutions to prevent disconnection from Chromium:

**- Patching the code like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53957525/8517006) (preferable)**:
Run the snippet before running any other Pyppeteer commands

```py
def patch_pyppeteer():
    import pyppeteer.connection
    original_method = pyppeteer.connection.websockets.client.connect

    def new_method(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['ping_interval'] = None
        kwargs['ping_timeout'] = None
        return original_method(*args, **kwargs)

    pyppeteer.connection.websockets.client.connect = new_method

patch_pyppeteer()
```

**- Change the [trouble making library](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/175)**:
Downgrade `websockets` package to `websockets-6.0` e.g via 
`pip3 install websockets==6.0 --force-reinstall` (in your virtual environment)

**- Change the code base**
as described in this [pull request](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/pull/160/files), which will be hopefully merged soon.